# Matplotlib plot for kNN classifier

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am trying to plot the accuracy of the kNN algorithm test result against the number of features passed by the chi2 using Matlab plot, but I am not sure how to extract the score so it is on the y-axis. For a fact I know the number of features passed should be on the x-axis.

It would also print out the highest score with the corresponding feature.

My code is below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=50,
                           n_features=6,
                           n_informative=3,
                           n_classes=2,
                           random_state=10,
                           shuffle=True)


# Creating a dataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Feature 1':X[:,0],
                                  'Feature 2':X[:,1],
                                  'Feature 3':X[:,2],
                                  'Feature 4':X[:,3],
                                  'Feature 5':X[:,4],
                                  'Feature 6':X[:,5],
                                  'Class':y})

df = df.abs()
y = df['Class']
X = df.drop('Class', axis=1)



i = 0

for i in range(1,6):
    i = i +1

    X_new = SelectKBest(chi2, k=i).fit_transform(X, y)

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_new ,y, 
                                                    stratify=y, 
                                                    random_state=66, 
                                                    test_size=0.3, 
                                                    shuffle = True)


    clf = KNeighborsClassifier()

    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)



#plt.xlabel("Number of features selected")
#plt.ylabel("Test Accuracy Score")
```

Comment: Which score do you want, accuracy?

Comment: @czr yes the accuracy on the test set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score` to compute the accuracy on the test set. Then store this accuracy in a list for every loop iteration.

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

Comment: can you please apply it to the above code along with graph output ?

Comment: @anyways to return the top score and the corresponding features ? or feature ?